# Can you pass an enum class to a method (java)

Tags: java, generics, enums, generic-programming

I want to pass a specific enum class to a method. Is this possible? The method would accept any enum. I am trying to create a function that will take a type of enum and make a menu out of it, returning the enum that was selected.

An example enum class

```
  public enum METHODOFTRANSPORTATION {
        CAR("car"), BUS("bus"), COMMUTTER_RAIL("commuter rail"),MAINMENU("GO TO MAIN MENU");

        private String choice;

        METHODOFTRANSPORTATION(String choice){
            this.choice = choice;
        }

        public String getMethodOfTransportation(){
            return choice;
        }
    }
```

My Example class implementing the enum

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ticket{

    private static HashMap<Integer, Ticket> hm= new HashMap<>();
    private int ticketID = 0;

    private METHODOFTRANSPORTATION methodOfTransportation;

    Ticket(){
        //Call method of Transportation to create ticket
        //GETTING ERROR HERE!
        this.methodOfTransportation = createMethodOfTransportation(METHODOFTRANSPORTATION);
    }

    Ticket(METHODOFTRANSPORTATION methodOfTransportation){
        this.methodOfTransportation = methodOfTransportation;
    }

    public Enum<?> getMethodOfTransportation() {
        return methodOfTransportation;
    }   

    public Enum<?> createMenuChoice(Enum<?> e) {
        System.out.println("**************************");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;
        boolean intFlag = false;
        Enum<?> mot;

        //Validate user input for menu selection
        do{
            //Print our Enums allowed variables
            for(int i=0; i< e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().length; i++){
                System.out.printf("%d. %s",i,e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu entry (");
            for(int i = 0; i< e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().length; i++){
                if(i == e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().length){
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(i + ",");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("> ");

            if(s.hasNextInt()){
                input = s.nextInt();
                for(int i = 0; i< e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().length; i++){
                    if(input == i){
                        //*********************************************
                        //HOW DO I RETURN THE CORRESPONDING VALUE HERE?
                        //*******************************************
                        mot =  ;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                s.next();
            }
        }
        while(false);

        //WHAT SHOULD I RETURN HERE??
        return METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.CAR;
    }


}
```

Is this even possible? I just want one method that will take any class of enum, and return the enum value. Is there a better way to do this??

Essentially my driver class would look like

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Ticket t = new Ticket();

        Enum<?> mot = t.getMethodOfTransportation();
        if(mot == METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.CAR){
            //....
        }
        //...

        //OR
        /*
         * switch(mot){
         *      case(METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.CAR): ...
         *      ...
         *      ...
         * }
         */
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you want any class of enum when you only care about `METHODOFTRANSPORTATION`?

Comment: @Makoto I think it's just an example. `createMethodOfTransportation` probably should have a more generic name, like `selectEnumValue`, since it should be independent from the enum name.

Comment: @BoppreH:  No, it really looks like they're trying to do a lot more work than they need to just to access either the cardinal values or internal values of their declared enumeration.  Generics here makes *no* sense.

Comment: I want to be able toto create a menu of METHODOFTRANSPORTATION, and other types of menus. So I might have a subclass of ticket that calls the create menu class, with a different type of ENUM.

Comment: @Makoto I agree Makoto, I think the `generics` tag here is mistaken. But the example looks ok and makes the question clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of referring to a class in Java is `ClassName.class`. So your line would be:

```
this.methodOfTransportation = createMethodOfTransportation(METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.class);
```

`METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.class` returns a `Class`-type object. You can then use reflection to inspect its name, possible values, etc. [Here is more info on enum reflection.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html)

The name `createMethodOfTransportation` would not be appropriate though, since it wouldn't have anything to do with the specific enum `METHODOFTRANSPORTATION`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.  You can declare your method like this:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T doSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
     EnumSet<T> all = EnumSet.allOf(clazz);
     ......
}
```

Or you can even avoid the whole `Class<T>` part and just ask for an `EnumSet` of choices:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T menu(EnumSet<T> options) {
     List<T> lst = new ArrayList(options);
     int idx;
     // display the list and prompt for idx
     return lst.get(idx);
}
```

And then you would call it as:

```
METHODOFTRANSPORTATION mot = menu(EnumSet.allOf(METHODOFTRANSPORTATION.class));
```

And now you don't have to mess around with reflection.  Let `EnumSet` do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I have found a solution. @BoppreH THANKYOU!!

Ticket.java createMenuChoice method

```
    //Using introspection
    public Enum<?> createMenuChoice(Class<?> c) {
        //Variables
        int input = -1;
        Enum<?> output = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            //Print Menu
            for(int i = 0; i < c.getEnumConstants().length; i++){
                System.out.printf("%d. %s\n",i+1,c.getEnumConstants()[i].toString());
            }

            //Get Selection
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu entry");

            if(s.hasNextInt()){
                input = s.nextInt();
                for(int i = 0; i < c.getEnumConstants().length; i++){
                    if(input == i + 1){
                        return (Enum<?>) c.getEnumConstants()[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                s.next();
            }
        }while(true);
    }
}
```

Driver.java I can call this using

```
MainMenu inputMm = (MainMenu) t.createMenuChoice(MainMenu.class);
```

and then check for entries with

```
if(inputMm == MainMenu.BUY_PASS){
} ....
```